# regex limiting wildcards for url folders

Tags: regex

I'd like to set up a regular expression that matches certain patterns for a  URL:

`http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/anything/anything/index.html`

This matches, and gets the job done:

`/^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/.*\/.*\/index\.html([\?#].*)?$/.test(location.href)`

I'm unsure how to limit the wildcards to one folder each. So how can I prevent the following from matching:

`http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/index.html`

(note: folder 5+ is what I want to prevent)

Thanks!

Comment: instead of `.*`, match `[^/]+` (I changed the `*` to `+`; revert that if `//` is ok (empty folder).

Comment: Thanks everyone for really great answers!! (gonna be hard to accept just one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` matches any character.

`[^/]` matches any characters except `/`.

Since the `/` character marks the begining and end of regex literals, you may have to escape them like this: `[^\/]`.

So, replacing `.*` by `[^\/]*` will do what you want:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/index\.html([\?#].*)?$/.test(location.href)
```

Comment: Thanks! (doesn't look like the escaping is necessary, its working without... but adding the escaping slash also works!)

Answer (score 2):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/(?:\w+\/){1,3}index\.html([\?#].*)?$/
```

Change the number **3** to the maximum depth of folders possible.

Answer (score 1):

`/^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/index\.html([\?#].*)?$/`

I don't remember whether we should escape the slashes within the `[]`. I don't think so.

EDIT: Aknoledging tom's comment using + instead of *:
`/^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/[^/]+\/[^/]+\/index\.html([\?#].*)?$/`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/\([^/]*\/\)\{2\}/
```

And you can change 2 to whatever number of directories you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
^http:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/(\w*\/){2}index\.html([\?#].*)?$/.test(location.href)
```