# How to URL folder path regex?

Tags: regex

i'm filtering regex result URL path folder

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715357/regex-limiting-wildcards-for-url-folders
```

i use regex expression

```
\\/[^\\s/\\/]+
```

so

> /stackoverflow.com/questions/16715357/regex-limiting-wildcards-for-url-folders

but, i want to folder path only...

> /questions/16715357/regex-limiting-wildcards-for-url-folders

this regex expression add expression?

Comment: Is this for Java or JavaScript? They are two entirely different languages.

Comment: sry. java / javascript tag delete

Answer (score 0):

Try the following [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/OYvzvk/1)

**Regex description:**

- `\.` match a dot
- `\w+` for matching top level domain
- `\/` for matching slash after top level domain
- `(.*)` capturing group for rest of the URL.

```js
const str = '/stackoverflow.com/questions/16715357/regex-limiting-wildcards-for-url-folders';
const result = str.match(/\.\w+\/(.*)/);
console.log(result[1])
```

Comment: i want to result this one